# Mi programa debería retornarme un list, pero no lo retorna y se queda en blanco

Tags: c++

Mi programa recibe un archivo de texto que contiene los includes de un programa de c++ mezclado con otras palabras, como por ejemplo:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
```

debe encontrar un include, extraer lo que viene luego (del include) y buscar si tiene los signos < o el string .h para insertarlo en una lista. Mi función debe devolver dicha lista. Pero cuando lo corro, nada sucede. Adjunto mi código.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

list<string> ListarIncludes(string str) {
    fstream arch(str);
    list<string>l;
    string linea;
    string es;
    char c;
    while(arch >> linea) {
        if(c == ' ') {
            string def = linea.substr(linea.find(c) + 1);
            size_t greater = def.find('<');
            size_t dotH = def.find('"');
            if(greater != string::npos) {
                l.push_back(def);
            } else if(dotH != string::npos) {
                l.push_back(def);
            }
        }
    }
    return l;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    list<string>l = ListarIncludes("codigo.txt");
    for(auto i = begin(l); i != end(l); ++i) {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dejas `c` sin inicializar. ¿ Quizás querías hacer `c = linea.front( )` ? Pero entonces, si la línea no comienza con un espacio ... ¿ Que debe de pasar ? No entiendo tu código O_O

Comment: Lo que quería hacer con el char es determinar si tiene un espacio, y ahí cortar la línea, por eso no sé bien cómo hacerlo :)))

Answer (score 1):

Las variables no inicializadas se quedan con un valor residual en memoria. El valor es indeterminado. Puedes almacenar 256 valores diferentes en una variable de tipo `char`, 255 de esos valores no son el espacio `' '`.

La condición `if(c == ' ')` que tienes dentro del bucle `while` seguramente no se cumple nunca, porque `c` nunca es `' '`.

Inicializa tus variables:

```
char c = ' ';
```